# Different objects

Tags: android, object

In an app I'm making I have an Object to a class called Preferences in my MainMenu activity. I want to use this object in several pages. In the object is a class which contains an array with numbers. When I use it in another activity (Film) it changes one of the numbers in the object. Then I go back to the main menu and into a new activity (CurrentPrefs) in which I display the array of numbers on the screen. When I displayed the numbers they didn't contain the changes made in the Film file. So I started testing around with the variables a bit.

When I start the MainMenu, which is the start activity, it sets the object. Then when I enter film and check the object it still has the same name (object.toString()). I also checked to make sure that the values where changed correctly which they were.

Next I went back to MainMenu and checked again. The object still had the same name and the value were also like I changed them in Film.

Finally I entered the CurrentPrefs activity and there it goes wrong. The object suddenly has a different name and it also no longer contains the changes I made to it.

Why has the object changed and, more importantly, how can I make sure it doesn't change and stays the same everywhere?

Comment: `static` should help.  But you may want to read about `sharedPreferences`

Comment: It is a public static object.

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: Or extending application class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of reasons why your object's values changed. Perhaps the previous `Activity` got destroyed and recreated without you realizing it.

You should check out Android's `SharedPreference` class. It is a way to store, edit, and retrieve preferences and have access to them in any `Activity`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Thanks, I will use that.

Answer (score 1):

If you well know activity's lifecycle you can also understand why it happens. Probably some of your operation are delegated to `onResume()` method which is called whenever activity comes back from `onPause()` or immediately after `onCreate()`, while other operations reside in `onCreate()` called only when activity starts or after `onDestroy()`. I advise you to control this and trying to move all `setText()` in `onResume()` so that every updated object's variable will be read again.